# Flutter Listview.Builder Not Updating

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, setstate

In my app, there is a Social page where users can message each other. A list that contains all conversations for a logged in user is being rendered by a `Listview.Builder`.  When the user receives a message in a conversation that isn't at the top of the list, I want to move it to the top of the list, I do that by calling the **reorderConversations** function.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    if(data_retrieved) {
      cancel_loading_indicator();
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: returnRefreshIndicator(
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                returnScrollableListView(),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // when a conversation gets a new message, this function places it at the top of the conversation list
  Future<void> reorderConversations() async {
    print("------ List Before Sorting ------");
    for(int i=0; i<conversations.length; i++) {
      print("Conversation id: ${conversations[i].getReceivingUser.getFullName}");
    }

    setState(() {
      conversations.sort((b, a) => a.getLatestMessageTimestampAsDatetime.compareTo(b.getLatestMessageTimestampAsDatetime));
    });

    print("------ List After Sorting -------");
    for(int i=0; i<conversations.length; i++) {
      print("Conversation id: ${conversations[i].getReceivingUser.getFullName}");
    }
  }

// builds and returns the scrollable view that will hold conversations for the user to view
  Widget returnScrollableListView() {
    return Expanded(
        child: returnScrollbar(
          scroll_controller,
          ListView.builder(
            controller: scroll_controller,
            keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
            itemCount: conversations.length, 
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ConversationEntry(
                local_user: widget.local_user,
                local_conversation: conversations[index],
                reorder_conversations: reorderConversations,
              );
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

While the function works and re-orders the conversation objects so the one with the most recent message is at the top, it doesn't visually update the `Listview.Builder`.  In the below screenshot you can see **Matthew Burns** sends a new message, although he remains in index 1 instead of index 0:

[image: Image of new message]

In the console log you can see the function swapped the entries:

[image: Image of logs]

If I click on the **Jack Lincoln** conversation in index 0, it will direct me to the conversation with **Matthew Burns**.  So although the re-ordering of the list is happening, it's just not being visually updated in the listview.builder.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you write super.build(...); ? You should remove It . It Is not needed, It could altered the updates.

Comment: It was recommended by Flutter to add super.build(context) since I wanted this page to be kept alive and not re-built when the user navigates away (it's one of the primary home pages).



class _SocialHomeState extends State<SocialHome> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SocialHome> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;